# Getting Apache to support application/x-httpd-php53 mime type

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a Joomla installation that needs the following directive remotely:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php53 .php
```

Locally, Apache only recognizes x-httpd-php (no version).  I'm running only 5.3 locally.  How can I "alias" `application/x-httpd-php53` to be handled the same as `application/x-httpd-php`?

Comment: Have you tried: `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php53 .php` and `SuPHP_ConfigPath /System/Path` in .htaccess?

Comment: I need to install suPHP for that?

Comment: Try it without that line, it is not mandatory.

Comment: It treats the php file as a download, responding with a `Content-Type: application/x-httpd-php53` header

Comment: That message is new to me. Normally `AddHandler` and `SuPHP_ConfigPath /system/path` (Without trailing slash) to php.ini is all it's needed. `suPHP' module should be enabled, so give it a try with the last line pointing to the directory where php.ini is.

Comment: I don't have suPHP installed :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a workaround.  This seems like a common problem.  Production hosts frequently allow choosing a version of php based on that `AddType` directive.  I want to ignore it for local development.

Using mod_rewrite works for this (requires setting an environment variable with `SetEnvIf`):

```
RewriteEngine On

# Use PHP 5.3
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTP_ENVIRONMENT} !^development$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.php$
RewriteRule ^ - [H=application/x-httpd-php53]
```